# R - dblyr optionaly filter

Tags: r, dplyr

I load data from database this way.

```
dt <-
  data.frame(
    id = seq(1, 100, 1)    
  )

getdt <-
  tb("db", "table") %>% 
  filter(id %in% !!dt$id) %>% 
  collect()
```

Sometimes could happen that dt object is not present at all. Is it possible to call query without this ugly if else? I'd like to keep only simple select above.

```
if (exists("dt")) {
  getdt <-
    tb("db", "table") %>% 
    filter(id %in% !!dt$id) %>% 
    collect()
} else {
  getdt <-
    tb("db", "table") %>% 
    collect()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your code breaks if dt is not available, you can use try catch:

```
tryCatch({
    getdt <-
    tb("db", "table") %>% 
    filter(id %in% !!dt$id) %>% 
    collect()

}, error = function(e) {
     getdt <-
    tb("db", "table") %>% 
    collect()
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Yeah, but this is almost the same as if else solution.